# jQuery, different function output depending on var scope

Tags: jquery, scope

I wonder, why I'm facing two different behavior patterns depending on var scope?
The first one does perfectly well, displaying browser's window width dynamically:

```
  $( window ).resize(function() {
      var $winWidth = $(window).width();
      $('#stop p').remove();
      $( "#stop" ).prepend( "<p>Actual window width: " + $winWidth + "</p>" );
    });
```

The second and the third ones display only one fixed size from which window had been resized initially:

```
    var $winWidth = $(window).width();   
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $('#stop p').remove();
  $( "#stop" ).prepend( "<p>Actual window width: " + $winWidth + "</p>" );
});
```

The third one:

```
 $(function(){
 var $winWidth = $(window).width();   
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $('#stop p').remove();
  $( "#stop" ).prepend( "<p>Actual window width: " + $winWidth + "</p>" );
});
 });
```

I was expecting the same behavior for all of that cases, excerpt the global scope var (the second) can  be used by any function within document and jQuery scope (the third) can be used  by any function inside

```
$(function(){
// Do something....
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with variable scope. It has to do with variable **value**. In your second and third examples, you're only setting the `$winWidth` variable **once**, when the page is initially displayed. When it's resized later, you use that old value instead of the current value.

To use the width as of when the resize occurs, you have to set the variable's value *inside* the `resize` handler. Doesn't matter what the *scope* of that variable is. That is, all of these work:

```
// 1. This works
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var $winWidth = $(window).width();
    $('#stop p').remove();
    $( "#stop" ).prepend( "<p>Actual window width: " + $winWidth + "</p>" );
});

// 2. So does this
var $winWidth;
$( window ).resize(function() {
    $winWidth = $(window).width();   
    $('#stop p').remove();
    $( "#stop" ).prepend( "<p>Actual window width: " + $winWidth + "</p>" );
}); 

// 3. So does this
$(function(){
    var $winWidth;
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        $winWidth = $(window).width();   
        $('#stop p').remove();
        $( "#stop" ).prepend( "<p>Actual window width: " + $winWidth + "</p>" );
    });
});
```

As you can see, scope isn't what's making it work/not work. It's *when* we set the value that makes it work/not work.

That said, you should always scope a variable as *narrowly as possible*, which would argue for #1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it.